# Unable to proceed with debugging

Tags: spring-boot

I am working with a spring boot project , which deals with redirect attributes . I want to debug my application and its getting stuck at this point .

```
2020-03-25 20:28:47.785  INFO 13073 --- [           main] .e.d.SpringRedirectattributesApplication : Starting SpringRedirectattributesApplication on rajgopal with PID 13073 (/home/rajgopal/Spring-Boot/spring-redirectattributes/target/classes started by rajgopal in /home/rajgopal/Spring-Boot/spring-redirectattributes)
2020-03-25 20:28:47.792  INFO 13073 --- [           main] .e.d.SpringRedirectattributesApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

Here is my project structure

[image]

I am also providing the remaining code

SpringRedirectattributesApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRedirectattributesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRedirectattributesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.demo.controller" })
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            final InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
            bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return bean;
        }

}
```

RedirectAttributesExample.java

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@Controller
public class RedirectAttributesExample {

    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    public RedirectView redirectWithRedirectAttributes(RedirectAttributes attributes) {

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", "redirectWithRedirectAttributes");
        attributes.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectAttributes");
        return new RedirectView("redirectedUrl");
    }

    @GetMapping("/redirectedUrl")
    public ModelAndView redirection(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String some = null, some1 = null;
        Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
        if (inputFlashMap != null) {
            some = (String) inputFlashMap.get("flashAttribute");
        }
        some1 = (String) ((Model) model).asMap().get("attribute");
        model.addAttribute("redirectionAttribute", some);
        model.addAttribute("redirectionAttribute1", some1);
        return new ModelAndView("redirection", model);
    }
}
```

redirection.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Submitted  Information</h2>
    <h3></h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1. ${redirectionAttribute}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. ${redirectionAttribute1}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.baeldung.redirectattributes</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-redirectattributes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-redirectattributes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can any one help me to continue debugging the application . I get connection refused error 
when I hit this endpoint while debugging .

I was debugging the application to check the contents of *some1* variable

http://localhost:8081/redirect

Comment: For starters delete your `WebConfig` classes, as Spring Boot already does all that for you. Add `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` to your `application.properties`. Also be aware that using JSP with an embedded container has limitations (works only in a WAR file for instance!).

Comment: I was debugging the application earlier everything was fine   , I made few changes to my controller class and suddenly the debugger got stuck .